# Latex Beamer uncover image at first item in itemize

Tags: beamer, itemize, minipage, uncover

for my presentation, I want to uncover an image after the first item in a minipage environment in itemize. I used `\uncover<1->`, but for some reason, it will NOT uncover at the first item but ALWAYS uncover at the second.... Can anyone help me ? It is at the page 22 of my presentation.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[figurename=Fig.]{caption}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetheme{uniud}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{first-last}
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{biblatex}{Patching footnotes failed}
\newcommand{\pdfnewline}{\texorpdfstring{\newline}{ }} 
\newcommand{\framefill}{\vskip0pt plus 1filll}


\title{Title}
\date{\today}
\author[author]{Author}
\institute{institu}
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figure}
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}



\begin{document}
\frame{
      \frametitle{My title}
      \framesubtitle{My subtitle}
      \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
          \begin{itemize}
              \item My first item: \\ \pause %Here I want to pause before adding some more text with an arrow
              $\rightarrow$ text in my arrow \pause %i want to pause again before the next item, I woul like that my image uncover itself here
              \item my second item
              \item my third item
          \end{itemize}
      \end{minipage} \hfill
      \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
      \uncover<1->{
      \begin{figure}
           \includegraphics[height=0.9\textwidth]{My Image.jpg}
           \caption{here's the image!}
      \end{figure}
    }
  \end{minipage}
}

\end{document}
```

It shows me the image after the second item... What can i do ?

I use this theme: https://fr.overleaf.com/latex/templates/university-of-udine-unofficial-beamer-theme/zndkgxrjsdzt

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome! `\pause` really means that everything after that comes on the next overlay. So you may want to use `\uncover` and also the built-in `columns` environment.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{My title}
\framesubtitle{My subtitle}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
          \begin{itemize}
              \item My first item: \\  %Here I want to pause before adding some more text with an arrow
              \uncover<2->{$\rightarrow$ text in my arrow}%i want to pause again before the next item, I woul like that my image uncover itself here
              \item<3-> my second item
              \item<4-> my third item
          \end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\uncover<1->{\begin{figure}
           \includegraphics[height=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
           \caption{here's the image!}
      \end{figure}}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here `\uncover<1->{...}` around the image has no effect but if you were to use `\uncover<2->{...}` instead it would have.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried, and it did not work. Can it be because I'm at the page 22 of my presentation ? And also you don't have the command line:  \beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->} before your \begin{documment} and uncover is still working ? How wan it be ?

Comment: @user11659631 My answer definitely works, which is why I added a full compilable example. If you copy parts of it into another document, it may yield different results. This is why one should always provide a complete document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. How on earth should anyone be able to guess that you have (or do not have) `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}` if this is not indicated in your question?

Comment: I'm sorry I though \beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->} was mandatory for using \uncover... I can't add my all presentation because it's 22 pages and a lot of useless line at the beginning but I can add it.

Comment: And yes your code works  but when I'm adding it in my presentation (without \documentclass{beamer} \begin{document}) it does not I don't understand why....

Comment: @user11659631 It is not necessary to add `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}` to be able to use `\uncover`. You do not need to add 22 pages, but a document that contains the frame, starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`, can be compiled and illustrates the issue. Since crystal balls are rare these days, this is the only viable way to find out why things do not work out in your document.

Comment: Yeah sure I get it, I add it.

Comment: This is the theme I use: https://fr.overleaf.com/latex/templates/university-of-udine-unofficial-beamer-theme/zndkgxrjsdzt

Comment: @user11659631 Too bad, I do not have an `overleaf` account. The problem is `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}` plus perhaps something that comes with `\usetheme{uniud}`. If you add `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{}` before that frame, it works. You can add `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}` afterwards, if you really need it.

Comment: It works !! Thank you so much ! Sorry for all the issues...

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting the same result as both of you, which is `\uncover<1->` doesn't work (but `\uncover<2->` etc. work).

So if you just start from 2 instead of 1, all the overlays happen correctly:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{My title}
\framesubtitle{My subtitle}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
          \begin{itemize}
              \item My first item: \\  %Here I want to pause before adding some more text with an arrow
              \uncover<3->{$\rightarrow$ text in my arrow}%i want to pause again before the next item, I woul like that my image uncover itself here
              \item<4-> my second item
              \item<5-> my third item
          \end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\uncover<2->{\begin{figure}
           \includegraphics[height=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
           \caption{here's the image!}
      \end{figure}}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```